# How to count the number of true elements in each row of a NumPy bool array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count, boolean

I have a NumPy array 'boolarr' of boolean type. I want to count the number of elements whose values are True in each row. Is there a NumPy or Python routine dedicated for this task?

For example, consider the code below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> boolarr = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]], dtype=np.bool)
>>> boolarr
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

The count of each row would give the following results:

```
1
2
2
```

Comment: you can read [here](https://thispointer.com/count-number-of-true-elements-in-a-numpy-array-in-python/#:~:text=Numpy%20Array%20%2F%20Matrix.-,Use%20count_nonzero()%20to%20count%20True%20elements%20in%20NumPy%20array,in%20a%20given%20numpy%20array.)

Comment: As easy as `print( boolarr.sum( axis=1 ))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [48]: boolarr = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]], dtype=bool)
In [49]: boolarr
Out[49]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]])
```

Just use `sum`:

```
In [50]: np.sum(boolarr, axis=1)
Out[50]: array([1, 2, 2])
```

The `True` count as `1` when doing addition.

Or:

```
In [54]: np.count_nonzero(boolarr, axis=1)
Out[54]: array([1, 2, 2])
```